# Android Follow google+ page directly through button

Tags: android, google-plus, google-plus-one

I want to put one button to follow my google plus page through click on that button, means when i click on Google+ button that automatically follow my page, i much goggling but not find
exact,so any one please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry ! There is no custom button for a Google+ following page.i think, i am using below code is useful for you. this code is directly open Google+ page and default follow button.

```
public void openGPlus(String profile) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.plus",
                "com.google.android.apps.plus.phone.UrlGatewayActivity");
        intent.putExtra("customAppUri", profile);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/" + profile + "/posts")));
    }
}
```

call this method such as openGPlush("numeric page id");

Comment: there are no any direct way to do it ?

Comment: yes. this code is directly redirect open following Google+ page. @nirav this code use carefully in your example and see result.

Comment: this is good solution instead of my way,i want to do direct but anyway ,this is well for me to goto the that page and direct follow throght page,thanks @elesh

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support for a Google+ follow button. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/). There is however support for a +1 button as you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend).

If you really want a Google+ follow button, you could theoretically use a WebView and put a Web API follow button inside, as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/follow/)